# Equivalent of HTTPBasicAuth (python) in OkHttp (Android)

Tags: java, android, python, http, okhttp

I need to get auth key: `auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)` code in python. How can I get it in java (I use OkHttp for Android app).

Answer (score 0):

With OkHttp you can create an `Authenticator` like so on your `OkHttpClient` as such

```
OkHttpClient myOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
myOkHttpClient.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
            String credential = Credentials.basic("Username", "Password");
            return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
        }

        @Override
        public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

This should do the job. I found there is not much documentation around using Basic Authentication but I found some help from: [Android OkHttp with Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490057/android-okhttp-with-basic-authentication)

Comment: method authenticate works when server returns 401 error. The best way is set up credentials at Header in interceptor.