# Filling login form on website that uses raw form data

Tags: java, asp.net, http, post, form-data

I am trying to log into a website lectio.dk using the HttpsURLConnection in java. 
Initially I thought it would be as simple as posting a request to the website with cookies with corresponding username and password, but it doesn't let me in that easily.
The website uses an ASP.NET session id, which I can use to access the website, when retrieved from a browser.

When I look at the developer mode in Google Chrome it seems as if it is grabbing the login details directly from the text fields (and not via cookies), which, by my knowledge, is not possible to edit from java.
This i think because the form data containing the data from the two text fields is the only place where I see the login details written.

I would love if somebody could tell me if there is a way of programatically logging into this website and getting access to the website as a logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You could to load the page with basic authentication. Like that:

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
    String userPasswordEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + userPasswordEncoded);
    connection.connect();
    ...
```

This needs to be part of any request you're doing on secured content. Think if you're using a HTTP client library you could also establish a authenticate once flow enabling by enabling cookie support. E.g. [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) is a decent library for doing that. See also [Android OkHttp with Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490057/android-okhttp-with-basic-authentication).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering so quickly. I will definitely be trying OkHttp out. As for the other part, it doesn't seem like the website is using Basic Authentication. It is using a sessionId (ASP.NET), and as far as i can read, that shouldn't be nescessary when using Basic Authentication. Either way, it doesn't seem to work.