# Retrofit POST request w/ Digest HTTP Authentication: “Cannot retry streamed HTTP body”

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to implement digest authentication using Retrofit. My first solution sets an implementation of OkHttp's Authenticator on an OkHttpClient:

```
class MyAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
  private final DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();
  private final Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass");

  @Override public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
    try {
      digestScheme.processChallenge(new BasicHeader("WWW-Authenticate", response.header("WWW-Authenticate")));
      HttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest(response.request().method(), response.request().uri().toString());
      String authHeader = digestScheme.authenticate(credentials, request).getValue();
      return response.request().newBuilder()
          .addHeader("Authorization", authHeader)
          .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  @Override public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for GET requests through Retrofit. However, as described in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21370620/1112407), POST requests result in a "Cannot retry streamed HTTP body" exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.HttpRetryException: Cannot retry streamed HTTP body
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:324)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:508)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:94)
        at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:49)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:357)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:282)
        at $Proxy3.login(Native Method)
        at com.audax.paths.job.LoginJob.onRunInBackground(LoginJob.java:41)
        at com.audax.library.job.AXJob.onRun(AXJob.java:25)
        at com.path.android.jobqueue.BaseJob.safeRun(BaseJob.java:108)
        at com.path.android.jobqueue.JobHolder.safeRun(JobHolder.java:60)
        at com.path.android.jobqueue.executor.JobConsumerExecutor$JobConsumer.run(JobConsumerExecutor.java:172)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Jesse Wilson explains that we can't resend our request after authenticating, because the POST body has already been thrown out. But we need the returned `WWW-Authenticate` header because of digest authentication, so we can't use a `RequestInterceptor` to simply add a header. Maybe it's possible to perform a separate HTTP request in a `RequestInterceptor`, and use the `WWW-Authenticate` header in the response, but this seems hacky.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I ended up swapping out OkHttp with Apache's HttpClient, which has built-in digest authentication. Provide an implementation of retrofit.client.Client that delegates its requests to Apache's HttpClient:

```
import retrofit.client.Client;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import retrofit.client.Request;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public class MyClient implements Client {
  private final CloseableHttpClient delegate;

  public MyClient(String user, String pass, String hostname, String scope) {
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass);
    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(hostname, 443, scope);

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, credentials);

    delegate = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();
  }

  @Override public Response execute(Request request) {
    //
    // We're getting a Retrofit request, but we need to execute an Apache
    // HttpUriRequest instead. Use the info in the Retrofit request to create
    // an Apache HttpUriRequest.
    //
    String method = req.getMethod();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if (request.getBody() != null) {
      request.getBody().writeTo(bos);
    }
    String body = new String(bos.toByteArray());

    HttpUriRequest wrappedRequest;
    switch (method) {
      case "GET":
        wrappedRequest = new HttpGet(request.getUrl());
        break;
      case "POST":
        wrappedRequest = new HttpPost(request.getUrl());
        wrappedRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        ((HttpPost) wrappedRequest).setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
        break;
      case "PUT":
        wrappedRequest = new HttpPut(request.getUrl());
        wrappedRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        ((HttpPut) wrappedRequest).setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
        break;
      case "DELETE":
        wrappedRequest = new HttpDelete(request.getUrl());
        break;
      default:
        throw new AssertionError("HTTP operation not supported.");
    }

    //
    // Then execute the request with `delegate.execute(uriRequest)`.
    //
    // ...
    //
  }
```

Then set the new Client implementation on your RestAdapter.Builder:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setClient(new MyClient("jason", "pass", "something.com", "Some Scope"))
    .setEndpoint("https://something.com/api")
    .build();
```

Comment: Can you show your code for creating httpurirequest? Did you implement all the methods from that interface?

Comment: Hello I'm strugling to implement Digest Authentication with retrofit. There is so low information about this in the Internet. I tried your example, but missed the part "Then execute the request with delegate.execute(uriRequest)`." Could you explai it please? Thanks

Comment: So `delegate` refers to the `CloseableHttpClient` private final variable at the top. We are using that HttpClient to execute the `wrappedRequest` object. Hope that helped!

Comment: Isn't there still a disconnect here between the CloseableHttpResponse from executing the wrappedRequest and the retroFit Response object return required by the interface?

Comment: Yep, you would construct a new `retrofit.client.Response` object that draws its fields from response returned by `CloseableHttpClient.execute()`. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nucleartide/24628083decb65a4562c) for an example.

Comment: Looks like I was on the right track (I was mapping from the apache to the retro response in a similar fashion).  Your gist link will help, thanks Jason.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the *Retofit ApacheClient* implementation from https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/ApacheClient.java to your own source, rename it to MyClient and add this constructor:

```
public MyClient(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = (DefaultHttpClient)this.client;

    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass);
    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM);

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, credentials);

    defaultHttpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
}
```

Now you can use *MyClient* on your *RestAdapter* builder: `.setClient(new MyClient("user", "pass"))`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using OkHttp client with Interceptor, I'm used to tried three times to execute request. I created the interceptor below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.crmall.androidcommon.helpers.CacheManagerHelper;
import com.crmall.maisequipe.helper.ApplicationSystemHelper;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

/**
 * Interceptor used to authorize requests.
 */
public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();
    private final Credentials credentials;

    public AuthorizationInterceptor(String username, String password) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {

            String authHeader = buildAuthorizationHeader(response);
            if (authHeader != null) {
                request = request.newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", authHeader).build();

                response = chain.proceed(request);

                if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST || response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    response = chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }
        }

        return response;

    }

    private String buildAuthorizationHeader(Response response) throws IOException {
        processChallenge("WWW-Authenticate", response.header("WWW-Authenticate"));
        return generateDigestHeader(response);
    }

    private void processChallenge(String headerName, String headerValue) {
        try {
            digestScheme.processChallenge(new BasicHeader(headerName, headerValue));
        } catch (MalformedChallengeException e) {
            Log.e("AuthInterceptor", "Error processing header " + headerName + " for DIGEST authentication.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String generateDigestHeader(Response response) throws IOException {
        HttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest(
                response.request().method(),
                response.request().uri().toString()
        );

        try {
            return digestScheme.authenticate(credentials, request).getValue();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            Log.e("AuthInterceptor", "Error generating DIGEST auth header.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes after second request OkHttp client return response status code 400 or 401 then I process request again and it's working fine for me.